# JOOQ BadSqlGrammarException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

I want to make a repository that makes requests using JOOQ for my spring boot app. To do this, I generated the necessary code and wrote a function. But when calling the function, an error occurs about an invalid request.

I generated the code using the following code.

```
package com.example.jooccodegen;

import org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool;
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*;


public class JoocCodeGenApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Database database = new Database()
                .withName("org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase")
                .withProperties(
                        new Property().withKey("rootPath").withValue("migrations"),
                        new Property().withKey("scripts").withValue("master.xml")
                );

        Generate options = new Generate()
                .withGeneratedAnnotation(true)
                .withGeneratedAnnotationDate(false)
                .withNullableAnnotation(true)
                .withNullableAnnotationType("org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable")
                .withNonnullAnnotation(true)
                .withNonnullAnnotationType("org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull")
                .withJpaAnnotations(false)
                .withValidationAnnotations(true)
                .withSpringAnnotations(true)
                .withConstructorPropertiesAnnotation(true)
                .withConstructorPropertiesAnnotationOnPojos(true)
                .withConstructorPropertiesAnnotationOnRecords(true)
                .withFluentSetters(false)
                .withDaos(false)
                .withPojos(true)
                .withJooqVersionReference(false);

        Target target = new Target()
                .withPackageName("scrapper.domains.jooq")
                .withDirectory("scrapper/src/main/java/ru/tinkoff");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
                .withGenerator(
                        new Generator()
                                .withDatabase(database)
                                .withGenerate(options)
                                .withTarget(target)
                )
                .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
                        .withDriver("org.postgresql.Driver")
                        .withUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/link_bot")
                        .withUser("postgres")
                        .withPassword("123"));

        GenerationTool.generate(configuration);
    }

}
```

It was generated according to the following DB scheme

```
CREATE TABLE chat_link
(
    chat_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    link_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (chat_id, link_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (chat_id) REFERENCES chat (chat_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (link_id) REFERENCES link (link_id)
);

CREATE TABLE chat
(
    chat_id    BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    tg_chat_id BIGINT                           NOT NULL UNIQUE,


    CONSTRAINT PK_chat_chat_id PRIMARY KEY (chat_id)
);

CREATE TABLE link
(
    link_id     BIGINT       NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    url        varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    last_update TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_link_link_id PRIMARY KEY (link_id)
);
```

but when I try to use the following function

```
package ru.tinkoff.scrapper.repository.JOOQ;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.jooq.Batch;
import org.jooq.DSLContext;
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ru.tinkoff.scrapper.enyity.LinkEntity;
import ru.tinkoff.scrapper.repository.LinkRepository;
import static scrapper.domains.jooq.tables.Link.LINK;
import static scrapper.domains.jooq.tables.Chat.CHAT;
import static scrapper.domains.jooq.tables.ChatLink.CHAT_LINK;
import scrapper.domains.jooq.tables.records.LinkRecord;


import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.count;

@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LinkJOOQRepository implements LinkRepository {
    private final DSLContext create; 
public List<LinkEntity> findAllOrderByDate() {

        var res = create
                .selectFrom(LINK)
                .orderBy(LINK.LAST_UPDATE)
                .fetch();
        
        return res.stream().map(this::fromTableToEntity).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

the following error occurs

```
2023-04-29T12:22:00.851+03:00 ERROR 21212 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [select "LINK"."LINK_ID", "LINK"."URL", "LINK"."LAST_UPDATE" from "LINK"]
    at org.jooq_3.17.12.POSTGRES.debug(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:245) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator.translate(JooqExceptionTranslator.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator.handle(JooqExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator.exception(JooqExceptionTranslator.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.jooq.impl.ExecuteListeners.exception(ExecuteListeners.java:276) ~[jooq-3.17.12.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:356) ~[jooq-3.17.12.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:290) ~[jooq-3.17.12.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2837) ~[jooq-3.17.12.jar:na]
    at ru.tinkoff.scrapper.repository.JOOQ.LinkJOOQRepository.findAllOrderByDate(LinkJOOQRepository.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703) ~[spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at ru.tinkoff.scrapper.repository.JOOQ.LinkJOOQRepository$$SpringCGLIB$$0.findAllOrderByDate(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at ru.tinkoff.scrapper.service.LinkUpdateService.update(LinkUpdateService.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at ru.tinkoff.scrapper.service.LinkUpdaterScheduler.update(LinkUpdaterScheduler.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:358) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: The "LINK" relation does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:177) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:219) ~[jooq-3.17.12.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.executeStatementAndGetFirstResultSet(Tools.java:4590) ~[jooq-3.17.12.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:236) ~[jooq-3.17.12.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:341) ~[jooq-3.17.12.jar:na]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current (jOOQ 3.18) implementation of jOOQ's [`LiquibaseDatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-liquibase/) uses an in-memory H2 database to [simulate a migration](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-simulate-a-liquibase-migration-using-h2/) prior to generating code from that database. In H2, identifiers are in upper case by default, whereas in PostgreSQL, they're in lower case by default.

The simplest way to prevent this mismatch is to prevent generating quoted identifiers at runtime, using [`Settings.renderQuotedNames`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-name-style/), setting it to `RenderQuotedNames.EXPLICIT_DEFAULT_UNQUOTED`.

Since you're using Spring Boot, [here's how to inject a custom configuration of the jOOQ `DSLContext`](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-customise-a-jooq-configuration-that-is-injected-using-spring-boot/)

```java
import org.jooq.conf.RenderQuotedNames;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
 
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public DefaultConfigurationCustomizer configurationCustomiser() {
        return (DefaultConfiguration c) -> c.settings()
            .withRenderQuotedNames(
                RenderQuotedNames.EXPLICIT_DEFAULT_UNQUOTED
            );
    }
}
```